# innerHTML не изменяет данные

Tags: javascript, yii2

Всем привет, есть вот такая диллема, и я не могу понять что здесь происходит:

-- **Место действия:** отладочная панель Yii2

-- **Проблема поста:** нужно добавить динамический вывод размеров окна браузера в эту самую панель, есть вот такой скрипт кнопок:

```
<div class="yii-debug-toolbar__block">
    <a id="tt1" href="<?= $panel->getUrl() ?>"> 123</a>
    <a id="tt2" href="<?= $panel->getUrl() ?>"> 222</a>
</div>
```

И есть js код, расположен сразу после блока, прямо в этом же файле

```
<script>
    window.onresize = displayWindowSize;
    window.onload = displayWindowSize;

    function displayWindowSize() {
        myWidth = window.innerWidth;
        myHeight = window.innerHeight;
        // сначала пытался в этот элемент просто добавить innerHTML, не получилось
        // в логах нашел editable, на всякий пожарный поставил в true(не знаю
        // насколько это тут реально нужно и уместно)
        var tt2 =  document.getElementById("tt1");
        tt2.contentEditable=true;
        tt2.innerHTML ="'w:"+ myWidth+"'";
        console.log(tt2);
    };

</script>
```

Еще немного вводных данных:

1. Сама панель выглядит вот так:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Она загружается после после того, как загружается DOM
3. Замена судья по логам работает:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, вот при всём этом результат такой же, как и на шаге 1.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не учёл(или не знал об этой механике изначально), что данный скрипт ведёт себя таким образом

**Финальное решение:** благодарю @grinat за ваш вариант. В конечтном итоге, в файле toorbar.js после родного yii2 кода вставился мой кусочек:

```
 window.onload = displayWindowSize; // тут сработал сразу и без воопросов
    window.addEventListener('resize', displayWindowSize); // тут window.onresize ... не работал, нашёл работающий вариант
    function displayWindowSize() {
        var  myWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var  myHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var tt1 =  document.getElementById("tt1");
        var tt2 =  document.getElementById("tt2");
        tt1.innerHTML ="w:"+ myWidth;
        tt2.innerHTML ="h:"+ myHeight;
        console.log('123123');
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contentEditable не нужен, он превращает блок в редактор разметки. 
Скорее всего, ты не учел что эта панелька динамически подгружается через ajax запрос: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/blob/master/src/assets/js/toolbar.js#L50 поэтому где и что ты сумел изменить большая загадка

Comment: Вопрос как раз в том, как правильно в этот динамически вставленный  кусок вставить свой кусочек информации

Comment: @alex-khonko воткни все что есть в displayWindowSize в setTimeout с нулевой задержкой, если не сработает, то поставь больше, если не сработает, то меняй в модуле файл toolbar js на свой, и после подругзки тублара через аякс выполняй свой код.

Comment: Благодарю, ваш вариант с дописанием кода в toolbar.js работает великолепно. Можете обьяснить почему код, который(как мне кажется) шёл после общего js кода модуля, и должен был работать уже поверх всего кода, и зная весь загруженный ajax код, в итоге не заводился?

Comment: Для меня вообще загадка почему он выполнился и что-то отобразил в консоли) Как бэ не все так просто: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml Там кстати есть решение с `<img src="empty.gif" onload="alert('test');" />` - оно может сработать. Можно привести к такому виду, если лень еще и гифку втыкать: `<img src="empty.gif" onerror="alert('test');" />`